How to allow customers to update their sales channel in admin interface in a Shopware 6 plugin?
I'm working on an e-commerce platform where customers are assigned to sales channels. Currently, this information is stored in the database, but can only be updated through direct database queries. I want to allow customers to update this information themselves through the admin interface.
Here's the current structure:
Customers table has sales_channel_id and bound_sales_channel_id columns (both BINARY(16))
Currently updating via SQL:
UPDATE customer 
SET sales_channel_id = 0x495dd071471d403eaa97fdfb8258b0dc, 
    bound_sales_channel_id = 0x495dd071471d403eaa97fdfb8258b0dc 
WHERE customer_number IN ('388371','389093','388814','388790','388499','388353','388476')

I need to:

Add fields to the admin interface for selecting sales channels
Create API endpoints for fetching available sales channels and updating customer info
Implement backend logic for these operations
Add frontend JavaScript to handle the form submission

I'm not sure about the best way to structure this, especially:

How to securely expose the sales channel selection in the admin interface
Best practices for creating and structuring the API endpoints
How to handle permissions so only authorized users can make these changes

Has anyone implemented something similar? Any advice on the overall approach or specific parts of the implementation would be greatly appreciated.
